# numpyでcsvファイルを読み込み、(csvファイルのデータが入った)タプルを用いた辞書を作成したい

Tags: python, numpy, csv

【はじめに】
pythonでタプルを用いた辞書の作成を試みているのですが、エラーが起こり、作成できません。
恐れ入りますが、エラーの改善方法をご教授下さりますと幸いに存じます。
何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

【実現したいこと】
現在、グラフ理論を勉強しており、その過程で以下のような辞書を作成しております。

```
dicts = {(i_1,j_1):length_1, (i_2,j_2):length_2,..., (i_10,j_10):length_10}

i:出発するnode
j:到着するnode
length:iとjの間の距離
```

具体的には、添付しておりますtest.csvの数値を代入し、以下のような辞書を作成を目指しております。

```
dicts = {(2,20):100, (4,18):200,..., (20,2):1000}
```

【試したこと・発生している問題(エラーメッセージ)】
該当のソースコードを実行しますと、以下のようなエラーを出力します。
エラーをネットで調べてみたのですが理解できませんでした。
numpyに問題があるようですがどうしてもnumpyを使用したく、他のデータを読み込む方法(pandas等)は試しておりません。

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

【該当のソースコード】
辞書の作成を目指し、以下のようなプログラムを組みました。

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("test.csv",      
                  delimiter=",",   
                  skiprows=1,      
                  usecols=(1,2,3) 
                 )

keys = [(data[i:i+1,0:1],data[i:i+1,1:2]) for i in range(0,10)]
values = [data[i:i+1,2:3] for i in range(0,10)]

dicts={}
for i in keys:
    for x in values:
       dicts[i] = x
       print(dicts)
```

test.csvは以下の通りです。

```
fid i   j   length
1   2   20  100
2   4   18  200
3   6   16  300
4   8   14  400
5   10  12  500
6   12  10  600
7   14  8   700
8   16  6   800
9   18  4   900
10  20  2   1000
```

Comment: `data[i:i+1,0:1]`  などと書くと、これはスライス(リスト)になるので、本当は `keys = [(data[i,0], data[i,1]) for i in range(0,10)]` などとするのではないでしょうか。(`values`も同様)

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/357618　に回答が付いていますがそちらの方法では解決しませんでしたか？

Comment: metropolis様

ご返信下さりありがとうございます。

ご教授いただきましたプログラムで実行いたしましたところ、エラーを出さず出力することができました。
今後hashable、unhashableを意識してプログラムを組みたいと思います。

改めまして、ご教授下さりありがとうございました。

Comment: merino様

コメント下さりありがとうございます。

仰っていただきましたようにteratailの方でもご回答いただきました。
理解と返信に時間がかかり、こちらの方の返信が遅くなりました。
大変失礼いたしました。

ご返信いただきました皆様、またご検討下さりました皆様に感謝申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

[teratail にて lehshell 様に回答いただきました](https://teratail.com/questions/357618) ので以下に共有させていただきます。
改めまして、ご協力下さりました皆様に感謝申し上げます。

---

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

numpy.ndarray は unhashable なので辞書のキーにはできないということです。
（hashable なものしか辞書のキーにはできません）

このようにすればいいでしょう。
`range(0,10)` を `range(len(data))` に修正しました。

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("test.csv",      
                  delimiter=",",   
                  skiprows=1,      
                  usecols=(1,2,3) 
                 )

# keys = [(int(data[i:i+1,0:1]), int(data[i:i+1,1:2])) for i in range(0,10)]
# values = [int(data[i:i+1,2:3]) for i in range(0,10)]
keys = [(int(data[i:i+1,0:1]), int(data[i:i+1,1:2])) for i in range(len(data))]  # 10 削除
values = [int(data[i:i+1,2:3]) for i in range(len(data))]  # 10 削除
dic = {n:values[i]  for i,n in enumerate(keys)}
print(dic)  # {(2, 20): 100, (4, 18): 200, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

このようにもできます

```py
dct = dict(zip(map(tuple, data[:, :2]), data[:, 2]))
display(dct)
```

分解するとこんな感じ (コメントにより修正: `1:3` => `:2`, `3` => `2`)

```py
k = data[:, :2]   # keys: numpy.ndarray
v = data[:, 2]     # values: array like
k_t = map(tuple, k)
dict(zip(k_t, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.loadtxt — NumPy v1.21 Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) には `unpack` という keyword が用意されています。

> **unpack**: bool, optional
>
> If True, the returned array is transposed, so that arguments may be unpacked using x, y, z = loadtxt(...). When used with a structured data-type, **arrays are returned for each field**. Default is False.

この機能を使って以下の様にも書くこともできます。

```py
import numpy as np

i, j, length = np.loadtxt(
  'test.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1,
  usecols=(1, 2, 3), dtype=int, unpack=True)

dic = dict(zip(zip(i, j), length))
print(dic)

#=>
{(2, 20): 100, (4, 18): 200, (6, 16): 300, (8, 14): 400, (10, 12): 500, (12, 10): 600, (14, 8): 700, (16, 6): 800, (18, 4): 900, (20, 2): 1000}
```

> numpyに問題があるようですがどうしてもnumpyを使用したく、他のデータを読み込む方法(pandas等)は試しておりません。

とのことですが、pandas を使うと簡単に変換できるので参考までに紹介しておきます。

```py
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
dfx = df.set_index(['i', 'j'])['length'].to_dict()

pprint(dfx)

# =>
{(2, 20): 100,
 (4, 18): 200,
 (6, 16): 300,
 (8, 14): 400,
 (10, 12): 500,
 (12, 10): 600,
 (14, 8): 700,
 (16, 6): 800,
 (18, 4): 900,
 (20, 2): 1000}
```